# Tongue muscle mechanics

Tags: anatomy

All muscles work by flexing, different cells pulling onto each other.

So how does one extend the tongue and elongates it in order to pull your tongue out of the mouth?

Answer (score -1):

The tongue has an odd musculature different from skeletal muscles and it works more like spider legs by using  hydraulic power, that's why the tongue can push but every other muscle in the body can only pull.